# .NET IsolationLevel ReadCommitted transaction causing duplicate identifiers

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, transactions

The following code is designed to generate a unique number for every record created. However we are finding that on rare occasions, duplicate Consignment Numbers are being created for sequential records. The database is multi-tenant and we are storing the "Next Id" in a system setting for each tenant and updating as per the code below:

```
    private async Task<int> GetNextConsignmentNumberAsync()
    {
        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(new Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkOptions
        {
            Scope = TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        }))
        {
            var nextConsignmentNumber = await SettingManager.GetSettingValueAsync<int>(ConsignmentSettingNames.NextConsignmentNumber);

            SettingManager.ChangeSettingForTenant(
                CurrentUnitOfWork.GetTenantId().Value,
                ConsignmentSettingNames.NextConsignmentNumber,
                (nextConsignmentNumber + 1).ToString()
            );

            await uow.CompleteAsync();

            return nextConsignmentNumber;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see why this would be allowing duplicate numbers the transaction level? We were previously using "Serializable" but it also caused the same issue and according to the .Net docs "Serializable" doesn't lock for the Read transactions hence can read the same value twice and only lock on the update. We need help as our client is complaining about the duplicate numbers being generated even though rare.
Thanks!

Comment: Does everything have to be done via your ORM layer? If you can run SQL directly, `UPDATE tab SET value = value + 1 OUTPUT deleted.value` should update and return the previous value atomically, without having to worry about multi statement transactions.

Comment: The "previously using 'serializable' but it also caused problem" sentence is a classic. We see too many locks so we lower transaction levels here and then and it seems to work until... it doesn't any more. There's usually no magic, raise the isolation level back (you can also use guids for ids, but lots of change) for this specific transaction at least. You can also use SQL Sequences: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/sql-server-sequence-basics/ (again can mean lots of rework)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes we can run SQL direct, but prefer to do via the ORM where possible. This transaction should work and guarantee the isolation level so am trying to understand why we are getting duplicates and fix at the code level rather than the DB level. We may have concede at some point and go to the DB which has already been discussed.

Comment: @SimonMourier your assumptions about "too many locks" are incorrect. However we did previously use SQL Sequences when the applicaiton was a single tenant. However we now run multiple tenants and therefore moved away from sequences due to the inability to have a sequence per tenant. Do you have any suggestions for using sequences inside a multi-tenant DB?

Comment: Not really apart from creating a sequence per tenant (this is another story, but that's one in the thousands of reasons why I always recommend one db per tenant https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198406/multi-schema-multi-tenant-databases-data-isolation-through-composite-primary). Otherwise, with serializable it should work but it also depends on the rest of your .NET code. IMHO the async here is a bad smell (plus exact behavior can vary depending on ambient SynchronizationContext). Make sure you use a regular TransactionScope in only one thread from start to end.